# Has there been any development or long lasting influence of Leonard Talmy's work?

Tags: semantics, prepositions, cognitive-linguistics

I've read some of Talmy's work particularly that of his semantic analysis of the spatial organization inherent in the meaning of prepositions like "across","around" or "over" among others. I've found this pretty interesting and unique research compared to a lot of the other stuff he has been doing but I don't really see him mentioned outside of his papers from the 80s. His force dynamics papers were also quite interesting.

Does anyone know what he's been up to or if any work has been done more recently (last 10 years)in this vain? Seems like such interesting work and it almost feels as if it was just forgotten after the big boom of Cognitive Linguistics in the Late 80s and 90s.